# Textbook recommendation for Complexity?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm interested to learn more about complexity and would like a textbook recommendation. In my undergraduate degree I've done a couple of modules on relevant topics in computational complexity. I do not yet have any specific interests in the area, so I would prefer a textbook that introduces the basics well and explores problems in the different complexity classes, if possible. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be Theory of Computational Complexity by Ding-Zu Du. It introduces complexity classes such as P, NP , BPP, Polynomial Time Hierarchy amongst other. Hope this finds you well and good luck

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend Wilf's "Algorithms and Complexity":

[Algorithms and Complexity](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AlgoComp.pdf)

Chapter 1 deals with the basics much more clearly and intuitively (but no less rigorously) than any other source I've read. The remaining chapters are full of interesting examples.